# Using Radio buttons within a Dialog box

Tags: android, eclipse, radio-button, radio-group

I want to be able to off the user a choice of options and would like to off er some radio buttons within a dialog box. I have declared the radio buttons like this in the OnCreate section

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    if (id > 0)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lectsort_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lect_sort));

                builder.setView(layout);

        // Now configure the AlertDialog
        builder.setTitle(R.string.exsort_title);

        radio_date = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RBdate);
        radio_loctn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RBloctn);
        radio_stream = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RBstream);
        radio_date.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
        radio_loctn.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
        radio_stream.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);

        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
             }
```

The radio_listener procedure is declared like this

```
RadioButton.OnClickListener radio_listener =
       new RadioButton.OnClickListener()
      {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          // Perform action on clicks
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
            Toast.makeText(LecturesActivity.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
      }
};
```

However when the dialog is called, I get an Null exception error on this line

```
radio_date.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to get the ID of a UI element that is located within a dialog box you need to do it like this.

```
  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext); // your dialog creation method here
  RadioButton radio_date = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.RBdate);
```

If you use `findViewById` then you are trying to capture the view object that is associated with the current acitivity view (which you would have set in the `setContentView` API)

So it is trying to find a view with the id `RBdate` in the activity view which it is not able to find and hence returns a null.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm sure this is on the right lines. However I've added the following code                                Context mContext = getApplicationContext();                   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);                     RadioButton radio_date = (RadioButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.RBdate);        But I still get a Null exception error, am I declaring it in the wrong place?

Comment: Are you sure you getting the exception at the same place (for RBdate)? or for a different radio button. Run your application in the debug mode and step through to find out the exact location

Comment: Yes, I get the error here - radio_date.setOnClickListener(radio_listener); and also if I try a different way, I get the error here - if (radio_date.isChecked())

Comment: You were right Ravi, I went through it again and when I changed the code to RadioButton radio_date = (RadioButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.RBdate); it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Holy fu\*\*ing s\*\*t!!!! Wasted 4hrs on similar dialog problem and all because of not using `dialog.findViewById`! Someone should put up a big disclaimer about this!! (not a pip about this anywhere else)

Answer (score 0):

check the following code 
This is an alert with radio buttons on a click of button

```
final AlertDialog.Builder  builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //int states = {false, false};
            builder.setTitle("Select the item  that you want to delete from that item ");
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(id==0){

                    }
                    else
                    {

            });

            alert= builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

u try this and let me know